# literature about colonialism

Tags: colonization

I'm looking for one big, synthetic work about colonialism from 15th to 18th century. I need general history, included history of Spain, France, Portugal, Netherlands and England/Great Britain. Do you know any?

Comment: I just stumbled across a book that might help here; I've edited my answer.

Comment: This thread just gave me a lot to read.  I don't know whether to thank you or insult yo' mama.

Comment: I am converting this to a communit wiki. It has true historical merit, but it really doesn't ask a question that has one clearly defined answer.

Comment: World Systems Theory?

Answer (score 5):

[Eric Hobsbawm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Hobsbawm)'s [*The Age of Empire: 1875–1914*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Age_of_Empire%3a_1875%E2%80%931914), [ISBN 0-521-43773-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aBookSources/0521437733) is probably the best reference for this period, I would suggest. Whilst it's part of a trilogy about the long 19th century ([*The Age of Revolution: Europe 1789–1848*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Age_of_Revolution%3a_Europe_1789%E2%80%931848) and [*The Age of Capital: 1848–1875*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Age_of_Capital%3a_1848%E2%80%931875) preceding it and fourth book, [*The Age of Extremes: The Short Twentieth Century, 1914–1991*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Age_of_Extremes) completing the set), it's a particularly good set.

But it's relatively weak on the pre-19th century colonialism, as that's not the trilogy's focus. I believe [Hugh Thomas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Thomas)'s trilogy ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aBookSources/0141034483/), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aBookSources/0141034491/), [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aBookSources/0671511041/)) is meant to be one of the best works on the Spanish Empire. [Thomas Pakenham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Pakenham_%28historian%29)'s [*The Scramble For Africa*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aBookSources/0349104492/) is one of the definitive works on that set of events.

I'm probably missing something really obvious, but I can't think of a more comprehensive guide to the wider period you're looking at, I'm afraid. I hope this helps nonetheless.

**Edit:** Doing some reading on Wikipedia, it struck me that this might be a book that would suit you well: Anthony Pagden (2003). *Peoples and Empires: A Short History of European Migration, Exploration, and Conquest, from Greece to the Present*. Modern Library. [ISBN 0-8129-6761-5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aBookSources/0812967615).

Answer (score 5):

[The Pursuit of Glory: Europe 1648-1815](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pursuit-Glory-Europe-1648-1815-History/dp/0713990872) (Allen Lane History) is an excellent book on that time period. [Europe: A History](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Europe-History-Norman-Davies/dp/0712666338/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1330327233&sr=1-3) Norman Davies will give you a good grounding as well and has many references to more in depth books.

Comment: Of course. I totally forgot about _Europe: A History_. Definitely worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [*A Concise History of the Caribbean*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521043484) or [*The Caribbean: A History of the Region and Its Peoples*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226645088).

These do not of course cover Pacific, Africa, East Asia etc.